# SCSS arithmetic operation with string

Tags: sass

```
.selector {
    $width: '10px';
    width: (#{$width}/2); // output: "10px", but expected: 5px
}
```

The code above is self explanatory. Please correct me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `calc` function.

```
.selector  {
  $width: '10px';
  width: calc(#{$width}/2);
}
```

---

**Update:**

Solution based on "[Casting a string to a number in Sass](https://kittygiraudel.com/2014/01/15/casting-a-string-to-a-number-in-sass/)" article.

Sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/004b9bc6e30aa6d4d45b59065d30a0c0).

**to-number** function
input: '10px', output: 10;
input: 10px, output: 10px

```
@function to-number($value) {
  @if type-of($value) == 'number' {
    @return $value;
  } @else if type-of($value) != 'string' {
    @error 'Value for `to-number` should be a number or a string.';
  }
  
  $result: 0;
  $digits: 0;
  $minus: str-slice($value, 1, 1) == '-';
  $numbers: ('0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9);
  
  @for $i from if($minus, 2, 1) through str-length($value) {
    $character: str-slice($value, $i, $i);
    
    @if (index(map-keys($numbers), $character) or $character == '.') {
      @if $character == '.' {
        $digits: 1; 
      } @else if $digits == 0 {
        $result: $result * 10 + map-get($numbers, $character);  
      } @else {
        $digits: $digits * 10;
        $result: $result + map-get($numbers, $character) / $digits;
      }
    }
  }
  
  @return if($minus, -$result, $result);;
}
```

**to-unit** function
input: '20px', output: 1px;
input: '35%', output: 1%

```
@function to-unit($value) {
  @if type-of($value) != 'string' {
    @error 'Value for `to-unit` should be a string.';
  }
  
  $units: ('px': 1px, 'cm': 1cm, 'mm': 1mm, '%': 1%, 'ch': 1ch, 'pc': 1pc, 'in': 1in, 'em': 1em, 'rem': 1rem, 'pt': 1pt, 'ex': 1ex, 'vw': 1vw, 'vh': 1vh, 'vmin': 1vmin, 'vmax': 1vmax);
  $parsed-unit: false;
  
  @each $unit in $units {
    // str-index - find substring in a string
    // 'px' in '10px' for example

    // $unit is a pair of ['px': 1px] (item in $units)
    // nth(['px': 1px], 1) returns 'px'
    // nth(['px': 1px], 2) returns 1px

    @if (str-index($value, nth($unit, 1))) {
      $parsed-unit: nth($unit, 2);
    }
  }
  
  @if (not $parsed-unit) {
    @error 'Invalid unit `#{$value}`.';
  }
  
  @return $parsed-unit;
}
```

Functions usage. At first get the number from string. Second, get the unit from string. Then multiply the number by the unit:

```
.selector {
  $size: '10px';
  
  $number: to-number($size);
  $unit: to-unit($size);
  width: ($number * $unit) / 2;
}
```

Generated css:

```
.selector {
  width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: well it works but calc is not backward compatible. Isn't there any other solution to this or any typecasting feature in sass.

Comment: There is no built in feature in sass to cast string to number. You can do it manually. I will try to write the code.

Comment: Thanks! Please also suggest any library or third party code snippet to achieve the same

Comment: @Rajkishore Can you mark answer useful if it helped you :-)

Comment: thanks for efforts, It works for me. But compared to other scripting language, its many lines of code just to achieve very simple thing. Isn't there should be some native way to do it. Curious!.

Comment: Sass isn't programming language.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a string to define the value for `$width`, and then do the calculation within the `#{  }` brackets:

```
.selector {
    $width: 10px;
    width: #{$width / 2};
}
```

Output:

```
.selector {
  width: 5px;
}
```

`calc()` should only be necessary if performing calculations on dynamic values, but when all the inputs are statically known, then use the preprocessor for that.

Comment: This is the correct answer, however you don't even need to interpolate, just `width: $width / 2;` is fine.