# How to add an offset to stacked absolute elements created from a JSON array?

Tags: css, json, reactjs, sass, array.prototype.map

How do I add an offset for elements stacked using absolute positioning? I want each card created using the .map function to be slightly offset from each other so it's clear the cards can be swiped through. Is it possible to do this and if so how?

Main reactjs code:

```
   <ReactSwing className='Stack'>
                        {Data.map((Projects, index) => {
                            return <div className='Cards'>
                                <div className='cardHead'>
                                    <h1>{Projects.workName}</h1>
                                    {Projects.workTech.map((Tech, index) => { return <p>{Tech}</p> })}
                                </div>
                                <p>{Projects.workDescription}</p>
                            </div>
                        })}
                    </ReactSwing>
```

Sass styling:

```
 .Stack {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .Cards {
        position: absolute;
        width: 85%;
        height: 85vh;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 20%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 12px;
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-sunset-jqjst?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You want to center all the cards and then offset them from center with absolute positioning?  What do you mean by "slightly offset"?  How exactly do you want the final layout to appear?

Comment: The idea would be to have each card slightly lower or higher than the one prior to it so it's clear that it's a deck of cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sass you can iterate over children using the **[@for](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for)** rule.

Working Example:  https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-darkness-zulys?file=/src/styles.scss

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Sass:**

```
body {

  background-color: #444444;
}

.container {

  position: relative;

  .box {

    $SIZE: 100px;
    $OFFSET: 55px;

    width: $SIZE;
    height: $SIZE;
    line-height: $SIZE;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
  
    @for $i from 0 to 5 {

      &:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) { //CSS index starts at 1

        position: absolute;
        top: calc(#{$i} * #{$OFFSET});
        left: calc(#{$i} * #{$OFFSET});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks mate I'll definitely give that a go looks pretty easy to implement aswell! Will give you the answer if it works with my project

Comment: Thanks so much, mate worked a treat! Would there be a way to do this with an unknown quantity of items as I'm pulling from a Json array which will likely be updated in the future?

Comment: You could reassign a `:root` css/sass variable from JavaScript with something like `document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--num-cards", "20");`and since the for loop expressions need to be integers, not DOMStrings, you can use a [**string-to-number conversion function**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47633235/336929) to write the for loop something like `@for $1 from 0 through to-number(var(--num-cards))`

Comment: Alternatively, you could just write a high number in your loop to cover your maximum like `@for $i from 0 through 100 { ... }`.  It's ghetto and could be a pretty big performance hit, but it works.